# Can someone please explain to me why the 'health' var is not updated when calling the updateGame() func

Tags: python

Been looking online for some answers, however it's still unclear to me why the 'health' var is not updated when calling the getDamage() func

I'm on my first few miles learning python

```
health = 200.0 
maxHealth = 200
healthDashes = 20
dashConvert = int(maxHealth/healthDashes)           
currentDashes = int(health/dashConvert)             
remainingHealth = healthDashes - currentDashes 
healthDisplay = '-' * currentDashes       
remainingDisplay = ' ' * remainingHealth
percent = str(int((health/maxHealth)*100)) + "%"
gameOver = False


def updateGame():
    print(chr(27) + "[2J")
    print (30 * '-')
    print("")
    print("    |" + healthDisplay + remainingDisplay + "|")
    print("         health " + percent)                      
    print ("")
    print (30 * '-')
    print("")

def getDamage():
    global health
    health = 10



while gameOver == False:
    answer = raw_input("> ").lower()
    if answer == "help":
        print("")
        print(" you can use the following commands: h, i, q, d")
        print("")
    elif answer == "q":
        print("\n")
        print("Game Over")
        print("")
        break
    elif answer == "h":
        updateGame()
    elif answer == "d":
        getDamage()
    else:
        print(""" not a valid command, see "help" """)
```

Is there anything I can do to properly update the "health" var and disply a reduced health the next time I call the getDamage() func?

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a text-based game to run in a while loop and have different functions to update a primary function (updateGame) that display relevant info about the player's state like health, inventory items.

The logic I'm trying to implement is:
have getDamage() reduce the health var and then display the newly change variable with updateGame()

Many thanks

Comment: Be more accurate. What is the problem. When declaring `health` as `global`, you can modify the global variable inside function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

health will change to `10` when you call `getDamage()` but `healthDisplay`, `remainingDisplay` and `percent` are set at the first of script and won't change everytime that `healt` global variable is changed. so you must change them in `updateGame()` function everytime it's called. Also i guess `health = 10` must change to `health -= 10`!

```
health = 200.0 
maxHealth = 200
healthDashes = 20

gameOver = False


def updateGame():
    dashConvert = int(maxHealth/healthDashes)           
    currentDashes = int(health/dashConvert)             
    remainingHealth = healthDashes - currentDashes 
    healthDisplay = '-' * currentDashes       
    remainingDisplay = ' ' * remainingHealth
    percent = str(int((health/maxHealth)*100)) + "%"
    print(chr(27) + "[2J")
    print (30 * '-')
    print("")
    print("    |" + healthDisplay + remainingDisplay + "|")
    print("         health " + percent)                      
    print ("")
    print (30 * '-')
    print("")

def getDamage():
    global health
    health -= 10



while gameOver == False:
    answer = input("> ").lower()
    if answer == "help":
        print("")
        print(" you can use the following commands: h, i, q, d")
        print("")
    elif answer == "q":
        print("\n")
        print("Game Over")
        print("")
        break
    elif answer == "h":
        updateGame()
    elif answer == "d":
        getDamage()
    else:
        print(""" not a valid command, see "help" """)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the updateGame function, you never make reference to the global variable health. If you want health to change inside the function, you will need to access it.

This means you should have something like:

```py
def updateGame():
  global health
  health = updatedHEALTH
  ...
```

Then it should change each time you call the function